# C# read from a Word document

Tags: ms-word

I'm trying to read from a Word document and I want the computer to tell me what is written in document not to write itself in other place. So when I say the keyword "word" my program should open a dialog menu and let me to select a word file and tell me what is inside. The other keywords work. So here's my code and also my error.

```
case "word":
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
  object readFromPath = null;
  Document doc = app.Documents.Open(ref readFromPath);

  foreach (Paragraph objParagraph in doc.Paragraphs)
    ss.SpeakAsync(objParagraph.Range.Text.Trim());

  ((_Document)doc).Close();
  ((_Application)app).Quit();
}
```

And my error is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjKte.png)

Comment: line #5 and line #5: readFromPath is `null` reference. try to fill it properly

Comment: @radinator is correct, you need to pass in the filename that you want to open. In your case the path where the document is found plus the name of the document.

Comment: @MaartenvanStam if I set readFromPath = "C:\Users\N.Horatiu\Desktop" + "s.docx" it says that this "/" is unrecognized escape sequence and also I don't wanna pass every time the filename and the location, I just wanna select the document when the dialog menu opens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application.Documents.Open takes the full path and filename.

The path must end with \ and prefix the string with @ (or leave out the @ and double the backslashes \ as one backslash is considered to be an escape character)

```
 object readFromPath = @"C:\Users\N.Horatiu\Desktop\s.docx"

 Document doc = app.Documents.Open(ref readFromPath);
```